# Cannot connect to MySQL externally

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

I am trying to connect to my MySQL database that I setup on linux externally and it is not working. I have made sure I have the right IP and the root user is able to be used externally. I have tried numerous tutorials but nothing as worked.

Comment: How do you connect? What language? What Tool? Are you sure your password is correct? Maybe CapsLock?

Comment: What errors?  Try via the command line, and post us the output:  `mysql -h <host/ip> -u <username> -p`  If you're using a host name (DNS), include the output of `nslookup <host>`  On the target box, give us the output of `sudo netstat -lnp | grep 3306` and `sudo iptables --list`

Comment: Oh and this please too: `SELECT host FROM mysql.users WHERE user='<username>';`

Comment: sudo netstat -lnp | grep 3306 Output:
   `tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN`     
   `1140/mysqld`

sudo iptables --list Output:
`Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)`
`target     prot opt source               destination`

`Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)`
`target     prot opt source               destination`

`Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)`
`target     prot opt source               destination`

Comment: Oh and mysql.users does not exist

Comment: Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an other user for external connections on a mysql database.

I don't know why but the root user is not working for distant connections. Just create a new user and give it the right to be used externally.